# Change appearance of VIM Insert Marker on Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, vim, appearance

On my Windows machine I'm using gVim7.4 and when in insert mode, the marker changes to a thin line, much like in any text editor. But on my Ubuntu system, (VIM7.4) the marker is the same for both command and insert mode.

Is there any way to change this so that insert mode has the thin marker in Ubuntu as well?

I've looked a bit at both the vimrc files and can't see any specific settings I've made in the Windows one that set the marker like this.. Maybe its because I'm using gVim there..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gVim should be the "same" on different platforms.  But the reference to vim versus gVim makes it sound as if the work on Linux is done in a terminal emulator (which was not mentioned).  For those, there are only a few cases which vim would be using, based on the termcap entry: invisible, normal, and very-visible.  Most terminal emulators have only two of those choices.

Comment: It was gVim only apparently, so I resorted to installing it.